# Mixing char and string in C array init

Tags: c, arrays, initializer

I know that the following 2 initializers are equivalent:

```
char T1[]="abc";
char T2[]={'a', 'b', 'c', 0};
```

I have an array initializer like this:

```
char T[]={0x10, 0xF, 0xF0, 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 0xC1, 0xD0};
```

Leaving aside the signed/unsigned char potential problems, is there a way to mix the 2 styles of initializer, doing something like that (which doesn't work):

```
char T[]={0x10, 0xF, 0xF0, "Hello", 0xC1, 0xD0};
```

Comment: No, I don't think you can do it the way you want.

Answer (score 5):

You can't mix them like that. What you *can* do is to insert hex codes withing a string, such as with:

```
char T[] = "\x10\x0f\xf0" "Hello" "\xc1\xd0";
```

Keep in mind this will put a `\0` at the end of that array so you may need to adjust for that if you're using `sizeof` to get the byte count:

```
size_t bytesInT = sizeof(T) - 1;
```

Similarly, there *won't* be a null at the end of the `Hello` but you can fix that with:

```
char T[] = "\x10\x0f\xf0" "Hello\0" "\xc1\xd0";
```

You may wonder why the string is separated into three components. This is valid because a very early stage of the compilation process involves concatenating adjacent strings, meaning that `"paxdiablo"` and `"pax" "diablo"` are functionally equivalent.

One reason is for readability, but the *important* one is to ensure that the hex specifications don't "swallow" the following characters. It won't matter for `Hello` since the `H` is not a valid hex character but you can see the problem here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    printf ("%d %d\n", sizeof("\x20Hi"), sizeof("\x20Bi"));
    return 0;
}
```

This will output `4 3` despite the only difference (seemingly) in the two strings being a change of one character. The lengths are different because the `B` in `Bi` is actually consumed as a hex digit, being treated as `\x20B` (although `gcc`, for one, will warn you that the resultant value is out of range).

Comment: You have to be careful with `\x` though. For example `char T[] = "\x10\x0f\xf0Byee!\xc1\xd0";` wouldn't work as expected. Using string literal concatenation would fix it: `char T[] = "\x10\x0f\xf0" "Byee!" "\xc1\xd0";`

Comment: @Ian, good point, have incorporated your info into the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot mix the two styles, but you can include HEX characters inside a null-terminated string with [HEX escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C):

```
// Instead of this
char T1[] = {0x10, 0xF, 0xF0, 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 0xC1, 0xD0};
// Do this:
char T2[] = "\x10\x0F\xF0" "Hello" "\xC1\xD0";
// or even this:
char T3[] = "\x10" "\x0F" "\xF0" "Hello" "\xC1" "\xD0";
```

The only difference between the above and the initializer that you have is that `T2` and `T3` are going to have one extra byte with null terminator at the end.

The above syntax exploits the feature of C which automatically concatenates multiple string literals separated by whitespace.

Comment: Perhaps separate the string literals when starting text after a hex escape `"\x10\x0F\xF0ByeBye\xC1\xD0";`is a problem.  `"\x10\x0F\xF0" "ByeBye\xC1\xD0";` is OK